# Android: onActivityResult() is not ok

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to call contacts through the default contacts application in a simple list form. After it's done and the user presses the back button, the application should get the names of contacts but somehow the Activity Result - **resultCode** - is now okay so it cannot query anything; when I tried to do it although the result was not **Activity.RESULT_OK**, then it said the intent as a parameter of **onActivityResult()** has null value = **NullPointerException**.

If anyone has an idea to figure out this, would you help me? Below is my code.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
        displayContacts();
    }

    private void displayContacts(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
          case (PICK_CONTACT) :
             // The problem happens here. The resultCode is not okay and it throws NullPointerException at data.getData();
             if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                  String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                  Log.d("Main", "Name: "+name); // Test: display a name on LogCat
                }
             }
             else{
                 Log.e("RESULT_OK", "Error");
             }
          break;
        }     
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, when user is not selecting any contact the value in `Intent data` is returning as null and you are using `data` in your code:

```
 Uri contactData = data.getData();
```

This is why it is causing a nullPointer Exception. If this is not the case than paste your exception log.

Comment: Thank you mudit! I see because I used ACTION_PICK so I must select an item on the list.